# How jdbc.connection.getmetadata() is updated

Tags: jdbc, metadata, upgrade

When a Java application is connected to a database, does someone knows how the connection metadata is updated (ex: when another instance create a new table in the database) Does the driver upgrade automatically this information or when getmetadata()  is invoked an invocation through the network is required. 
I'm searching information for MySQL, postgresql, and oracle. 
Thank you for your help and your time .
Paul

Comment: An invocation through the network is required.

Comment: The drivers for MySQL and PostgreSQL are open source, read their sources. The will likely just query the information when asked for.